# How to save html/php page as pdf?

Tags: php, pdf-generation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Hi good day everyone,

Im new in php, im just wondering how can i save my html/php page as pdf file so that other users can save it on their computer for printing.

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You may use some free HtmlToPdf Services.

something like >>
http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/

Comment: Hi Raathigesh, is there other way where other users can just click a button in my page to save it as pdf?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, You may use http://pdfmyurl.com/ See the Advance options.

How to use / insert PDFmyURL in your own site

Just link the text or image people will use for downloading a specific page/url:

http://pdfmyurl.com?url=www.opentracker.net 

for example:
<a href="http://pdfmyurl.com?url=www.opentracker.net">download this page as pdf</a>

Comment: Yeah the site in this answers also offers this, see http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/save-as-pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you need to generate pdf on the fly: http://www.tcpdf.org/